# Resolving class that has extension methods with AutoFac

Tags: entity-framework, autofac, graphdiff

I am using a third party library **GraphDiff** which adds Extension methods to DBContext class. My Context class is inherited from Interface like following

```
 MyContext: DbContext,IMyContext
```

IoC contained register MyContext as IMyContext. Interface doesn't have extension method's signature and third. Now i am not getting how MyContext will have that extension method? If i create Object of MyContext it has that method but when it gets Inject it doesn't

Comment: Were the extension methods working in the past?

Comment: It's a Nuget package which offers extension methods. My Context implements Interface so that i can use Ioc on it . Now the issue is how can i make my Interface aware

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extensions methods are not part of the type, it is a C# [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). When you do :

```
myContext.ExtensionMethod();
```

the compiler will generate the following code :

```
ExtensionContainer.ExtensionMethod(myContext);
```

Where `ExtensionContainer` is defined like this :

```
public static class ExtensionContainer 
{
    public static void ExtensionMethod(this DbContext context)
    { }
}
```

When you use an extension method, the compiler will call a static method. See [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) for more information.

You can't use the extension method in your case because `context` is no longer a `DbContext` but `IMyContext` and the extension methods are defined for `DbContext` not for `IMyContext`.

If you want to use these extension methods, one possible solution is to add them to your interface.

```
public interface IMyContext
{
    T UpdateGraph<T>(T entity, Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>> mapping, UpdateParams updateParams = null) where T : class 

    // other methods / properties
}
```

And in your concrete context you will be allowed to use the extension method

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
{
    public T UpdateGraph<T>(T entity, Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>> mapping, UpdateParams updateParams = null) where T : class
    {
        DbContextExtensions.UpdateGraph<T>(this, entity, mapping, updateParams); 
    }
}
```

Another solution is not to rely anymore on `IMyContext` but injecting `MyContext`. This solution will make your application more difficult to test and will introduce a strong dependency with *Entity Framework*.

By the way doing so may break [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) but I don't see an easy way to solve this without big refactoring.

Comment: What if I inject MyContext and get rid of IMyContext?

Comment: It will work but test will be more difficult and your application will be highly coupled with *Entity Framework*

Comment: public static T UpdateGraph<T>(this DbContext context, T entity, Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>> mapping, UpdateParams updateParams = null) where T : class     //This is the signature of the extension method I am after . How can this be added to IMyContext

Comment: In MyContext it was complaining about <T>, added a new() after class in signatures // T UpdateGraph<T>(T entity, Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<T>, object>> mapping, UpdateParams updateParams = null) where T : class, new()

Comment: A third low touch/fast (but hacky) solution would be to just define pass through extension methods defined on `IMyContext` that attempt to cast the instance of `IMyContext` to a `DbContext` before calling the real method. You may have to refactor later, but it'll get you over a hump if you have a deadline to meet.